# Why is there no min-margin property in CSS?

Tags: css

Imagine I want to center my `.wrapper` with the classic `margin: 0 auto;`
But when the window shrinks I want to make sure that the wrapper has at least a 20px margin.

[image]

Where is the `min-margin` property?

Or rather, how should I simulate this?
(Padding on the body is not a good solution)

Comment: Why not set the width in percentage?

Comment: @SKeurentjes The site has a fixed width, and this is not something I can change.

Comment: You should ask what you need to know (and say it in the title, too), rather than a seemingly “why” question (such questions are seldom constructive).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this with [CSS3 Media Queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/).

```css
@media screen and (max-width:200px) {
    .wrapper {
        width:160px;
        margin:0 20px;
    }
}
```

In this example media query, if the window's width is no greater than 200px, `.wrapper` will be given an absolute width of 160px and a 20px margin either side.

MDN covers Media Queries in some good detail [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries).

> ...we have orders at job not to use media queries in this specific case.

In that case you can simply add padding to your `body` element:

```css
body {
    padding:0 20px;
}
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/5raRJ/).

Comment: Yes, that is a simple solution. However, should have mentioned it in the question, we have orders at job not to use media queries in this specific case. (I know... )

Comment: @JimmyRare I've added to my answer with a different solution.

Comment: Yeah, padding on the body won't work because we have a incoming header bar which is full width.

Anyways, I'll accept your answer. It's just a very unusual scenario.
min-margin would've done it. =D

Comment: @JimmyRare you could always adjust for the header by adding negative margins: `header { margin:0 -20px }`

Comment: Yes, I just wanted a more "clean" way.